# Count of Favorited entries in Solspace Favorites in a specific channel tag with a specific user

Tags: solspace, count

I need to show the number of times a user has favorited a specified set of entries. I've tried many ways, including different combinations of using Stash and Mx_calc, but have been unsuccessful.

The exp:favorites:count tag doesn't seem to allow this without help. I would like it to do something like `{exp:favorites:count entry_id="130|132|463" favorites_member_id="CURRENT_USER"}`, but this is not allowed.

I've tried setting the numbers of each entry with Stash and then adding them with Mx_calc but can't get that to work (below). Maybe there's a simpler way?

```
{exp:stash:set name="total-favorites" parse_tags="yes"}
  {exp:channel:entries channel="topic-content" search:topic-title="advertising" category="5" search:topic-view="IS_EMPTY" dynamic="no" parse="inward"}  
    {exp:favorites:count entry_id="{entry_id}" favorites_member_id="CURRENT_USER"}
  {/exp:channel:entries}    
{/exp:stash:set}


  {exp:mx_calc parse="inward" expression="sum({exp:stash:get:blah name="total-favorites"})"}
{!--OR--}
{exp:stash:parse trim="yes" parse="inward"}
  {exp:mx_calc parse="inward" expression="sum({exp:stash:get:blah name="total-favorites"})"}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

Comment: What's your use case? Are you looping  thru chanmel entries whilst outputting the logged in users likes or is this a separate call elsewhere on the page?

Comment: Not 100% sure of your question. Everything is included in the code above. Yes I am looping through the channel entries, and using the outputted entry id's to determine whether the logged in user has in fact voted (favorited) on each of those entries. I just need to get the total number of times the user has voted on all of those entries combined. (Getting the count for each entry id is no problem - getting the sum of each one according to the channel:entries loop is what is confusing me.)

Answer (score 0):

Well to start with you're capturing a single number, by adding stash around the EE channels tags, it will only ever capture/hold the last number or 0.

To hold all numbers you should use something like the following (**NOTE:** This is a theory and not verbatim code, refer the documents and experiment) I've done similar but not with Favorites so cannot confirm code of usage:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="topic-content" search:topic-title="advertising" category="5" search:topic-view="IS_EMPTY" dynamic="no" parse="inward"}  
    {exp:stash:append name="fav_count" scope="user" trim="yes"}{exp:favorites:count entry_id="{entry_id}" favorites_member_id="CURRENT_USER"}+{/exp:stash:append}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
//NEW - Add bogus 0 to end of stash
{exp:stash:append name="fav_count" scope="user" trim="yes"}0{/exp:stash:append}
```

What this does is append the result of the favourites tags, trims any whitespace which would kill the sum action (next), adds a scope to the current user as well as adding the "+" symbol, which we can now utlise like this:

```
{exp:stash:parse}
  {exp:mx_calc parse="inward" expression="sum({exp:stash:get name='fav_count' scope='user'})"}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

Assuming the stash capture results look like this:
`0+1+2+0+` the sum would render like exp:mx_calc parse="inward" expression="sum(0+1+2+0+)

Failing that (or variations). Wrap each result in a unique class and use Javascript to find, record, add up and inject into a result tag.

**UPDATE:**
Added a trailing '0' to the original capture (the trailing '+' was borking the math module.
Inside the math function, used single quotes rather then doubles.

**WORKING CODE!**

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="topic-content" search:topic-title="advertising" category="5" search:topic-view="IS_EMPTY" dynamic="no" parse="inward" }  
  {exp:stash:append name="fav_count" parse_tags="yes" trim="yes" parse_conditionals="yes"}
    {exp:favorites:count entry_id="{entry_id}" favorites_member_id="CURRENT_USER"}
    {if "{count}" != "{total_results}"}+{/if}
  {/exp:stash:append}
{/exp:channel:entries}

{exp:stash:parse process="end"}
{exp:mx_calc expression="sum({stash:fav_count})"} 
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Using exp:stash:append and the "+" seems like the right way to go. It turns out that process=“end” is also needed. I am testing the results with {exp:stash:get name="fav_count" process="end" trim="yes" scope="user”} but instead of returning the numbers to be added there is a string like M00o93H7pQ09L8X1t49cHY01Z5j4TT91fGfr+. I have checked the documentation and online help and have tried various additional tags like parse=“inward” but haven’t found anything yet to get this to work properly.

Comment: Updated my original answer. PS. You never need to add `trim='yes'` to the `get` call - it's a setter param.

Comment: Wow, I finally got it! Thanks for your help in guiding towards this.

I'm not sure why, but the append code started to work properly and I was able to use the plus sign at the end of the looped entries. I also had to use a conditional to remove the final "+". For the mx_calc code, I found some instructions on using the simpler version pasted above

Comment: Nice one, glad to see you got it working and picked up a little on the way :)